# Cannot add idea key scheme plugin to eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I have problems adding idea key scheme plugin to the eclipse, I'm using eclipse neo 3, I tried adding to "eclipse/plugin" but it won't find the plugin, also tried adding it to "eclipse/dropins/plugins" but then eclipse won't start

Comment: This? https://github.com/mknapik/ideakeyscheme

Comment: Yes, that is the plugin

Comment: I managed eventually, I just had to wait a lot longer than expected to load eclipse.